# How do I make the jquery animations smoother?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, animation, web

I am working on this website for my client, and I have decided to incorporate jquery animations. However, the animations aren't smooth and stutter, is there a way of making my animations smooth(er)? 
Here is my site: http://adamallard.info/eagle/

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is usually better to use css transitions when you can, which is possible in most all situations, and then just add / remove a class to get the effect you want. This will also unclutter your js and keep things in their own space.

Comment: I go with this answer, you should not put animation into Javascript / jQuery if you can use CSS transitions / keyframes.